# sent packet is different from received packet

Tags: networking, tcp, network-protocols

I use raw socket to create TCP packets, with focus on the sequence number and TCP flags(SYN, ACK)

I used one machine S to send a tcp ACK packet (flag ACK is set to 1)
and another machine R to receive it
these two machines are in different subnets, all in my school

meanwhile, I used tcpdump to capture the packets.

Strange things happens!
On machine S, the captured packet is as expected, it is an ACK packet
however, on the receiving machine R, the packet becomes a SYN packet,
and the sequence number is changed, the seq no is 1 smaller the expected and the ack_seq become 0!

what is wrong with this?
my guess is that the router/firewall modified the ACK packet to a SYN packet because it never sees a SYN SYN/ACK exchange ahead of the ACK?
is it possible or not?

the two captured packets are:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B09y_TWqTtwlVnpuUlNwUmM1YUE/edit?usp=sharing
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B09y_TWqTtwlTXhjUms4ZnlkMVE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: That is definitely weird, and it is unlikely that the firewall would attempt to set up the TCP session correctly, it should do the opposite and discard the packet as out-of-state.  Can you upload the captures somewhere?

Comment: yes, I add them!

Comment: The captures are not publicly available from here. Could you make them publicly available?

Comment: I have made them public

Comment: Packet 2 is the interesting one right?  It is issued as an ACK, but there is a SYN at the server end.  But what are packets 1 and 3?  It looks like tehre is already a session running with those ports?

Comment: yes, Packet 2 is what I need, but on the server it becomes a SYN packet. I sent a SYN packet to the server before, and then the server responded with packet 1 SYN/ACK, and since it doesn't get an ACK(it get a SYN, as I mentioned) it retransmit the SYN/ACK

Comment: How did you send these packets? Also, is DNAT or SNAT in use here, changing port numbers?

Comment: Can you make a TCP connection between these two devices using any program such as netcat, iperf, telnet etc? Also, are UDP connections OK?

Comment: yes, I can, and UDP is OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that you have the sequence numbers wrong on your ACK packet.  So the firewall in between sees your ACK packet with the wrong sequence and decides that the SYN-ACK never made it to you, and so re-transmits the original SYN packet to the server to get it to resend the SYN-ACK, which it does.

If you look at your trace in Wireshark, it draws the same conclusion - it doesn't see your ACK as part of the original session, but a new session using the same ports.